# Posting to Facebook wall during a game turns off the full screen

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

When I post to my Facebook wall while I'm playing games the full screen turns off automatically. That doesn't happen in my husband's account. How can I stop this from happening?

I would like to play and post to my wall keeping it in full screen mode.

Comment: Is the game you're playing a Flash game played within Facebook? Are you playing the game on the same computer within the same browser?

Comment: yes a flash game played on Facebook.yes in same computer and browser. and the problem only happens in my account.

Comment: you're playing the same game as well?